# Touch image on the background transparent in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have an image and my image is transparent. I have added the following code to my image:

```
on mouseUp
  --do something()
end mouseUp
```

When I touch the image on the transparent area, my script doesn't work. Now, I use a button instead of an image, but the button can't rotate. I want to use an image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution : You can add a control (like an image, graphic, button, etc.) behind your image and set it's blendLevel to 100.  This will make it invisible, but it will still respond to mouse / touch events.  You can then pick up the touches using the hidden object.

Comment: It works but as I understood, in addition, KemChat wanted to rotate the image as well and if you group the original image that has transparent background with the additional one with blend level 100 then you cannot rotate the group.

Comment: You don't need to group the objects - you could add another image object and rotate it the same as the original

Comment: (if it's an image with no transparent areas, then it will pick up the touches on the transparent areas of the original)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to remove the mouseUp handler from the image and put it in the card script;

`-- Card Script:
on mouseUp
   if the clickLoc is within the rect of img "XYZ" then doSomething
end mouseUp`

Note: if you need a mouseUp in the image to do something else then just pass the mouseUp when you finish the other actions. e.g.;

`-- Image Script:
on mouseUp
   -- do something with the image
   pass mouseUp
end mouseUp`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to set the image as an icon of a transparent button.